# How to create a link without href attribute on rails 3 with link_to?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

i'm not able to create a link without the href attribute with link_to

```
<a class="some-class" title="some-title"></a>
```

i was searching in some [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) but i haven't seen anything related to this problem.

FYI this type of link is provided to have a clickable item with the title attribute and without the classic '#' in the url. i'm open to other solutions to the problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just type it directly in the view

```
<a class="some-class" title="some-title"></a>
```

the link_to helper is used to get the baseurl

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [Tag Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html).

This should do the trick:

```
<%= tag "a", :class => "some_class", :title => "some_title"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each link should have `href` attribute.
You could set `href` to `#` like this:

```
<%= link_to "#", class: "some-class", title: "some-title" do %>
  Whatever
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is no longer true as of HTML5